# Were all of the Goosebumps monsters in the film?

Tags: goosebumps

A small number of Goosebumps monsters were heavily featured in the new movie. However, many more were seen in the horde of monsters.

Were all of the original Goosebumps monsters from the books present in the movie in some way? If not, which monsters were absent?

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typoes. Half-asleep questions with autocorrect get interesting!

Answer (score 4):

According to a fan-wiki [here](http://goosebumps.wikia.com/wiki/Goosebumps_Movie_Novel), the only two monsters which do not appear in the film (but were present in the books) is:

- The gargoyle from *I'm Telling!*
- The ghost from *Ghost camp*

There is a compiled list of all the monsters/villains present in the film [here](http://goosebumps.wikia.com/wiki/Goosebumps_(2015_film)), under the heading "**Monsters and Villains**", along with the books in which they appeared. The page also features interesting trivia about the film.

Comment: That's referring to the book based on the film, not the books on which the film is based.

Comment: I agree with OrangeDog. It seems in the book those 2 characters were named, but were they hidden in the movie? Are there production or promotional materials that help us ID the monsters? From the 2nd list I count 32 monsters out of 62 original books (some had the same monster, IIRC)

Comment: Sorry. I agree, I missed that part :/ It is possible to compile a list from the original 62 books, and then cross-reference them with the movie, I'll do this some time and edit my answer. I think there will be quite a few missing monsters